# Can not apply panel class in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In my project Bootstrap styles are not working for div and span classes.But Bootstrap styles are properly working for buttons.

```
<div>
  /*Can not apply style for panel*/
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">A Basic Panel</div>
  </div>
  /*Style for button is properly working.*/
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're using Bootstrap 4. Panels are deprecated in v4 as they've introduced cards.

> Dropped panels, thumbnails, and wells for a new all-encompassing component, cards.

[See migration details](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/)

Use `.card` instead of `.panel` and `.card-body` instead of `.panel-body`.

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">A Basic Panel</div>
</div>
```

Complete migration details :

- `.panel` to `.card`, now built with flexbox.
- `.panel-default` removed and no replacement.
- `.panel-group` removed and no replacement. `.card-group` is not a replacement, it is different.
- `.panel-heading` to .card-header
- `.panel-title` to `.card-title`. Depending on the desired look, you may also want to use heading elements or classes (e.g. `<h3>`, `.h3`) or bold elements or classes (e.g. `<strong>`, `<b>`, `.font-weight-bold`). Note that `.card-title`, while similarly named, produces a different look than `.panel-title`.
- `.panel-body` to `.card-body`
- `.panel-footer` to `.card-footer`
- `.panel-primary`, `.panel-success`, `.panel-info`, `.panel-warning`, and `.panel-danger` have been dropped for `.bg-`, `.text-`, and `.border` utilities generated from our $theme-colors Sass map.

Answer (score 1):

`cards` replace our `old panels`, so you should use `card` instead of `panel` as below:

```
//for example
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">Basic card</div>
</div>
```